# Facebook Marketing APi How to get campaign by id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i need to get campaign by id, but as i see from
[documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign-group) there are only one method `/{ad_account_id}/campaigns`

and i get all campaigns in result set.

How to use Graph Api to get only one item by id?

`GET` `/campaign/{id}` not working, how can i filter it by id? or even ids

`GET` `/{ad_account_id}/campaigns`

Comment: I’d assume that’s just a simple call using the campaign id, `/{id}` …?

Comment: @CBroe damn, you are right, it works, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be possible with just a simple call using the campaign id, `/{id}`

---

(Basically every object in the FB “universe” that has a normal ID, can be requested via that ID from the respective API.)

Answer (score 0):

You cam try

`https://graph.facebook.com/[VERSION_APP]/[CAMPAIGN_ID]` or `[ADSET_ID]` or `[AD_ID]/insights?fields=actions,account_id,website_ctr&action_breakdowns=["action_type"]&action_attribution_windows=["default"]&time_range={"since":"YYYY-MM-DD","until":"YYY-MM-DD"}`

But, I can't get Start date and EndDate of campaign